# Using dartdoc categories

Tags: flutter, dart, dartdoc

Trying to understand the purpose/usage of categories in dartdoc.

What do they do?  Do they re-arrange the output and group it in the categories?  Is there a complete example of how they are used?

**My Use Case**

I've generated a set of docs with dartdoc on a flutter utility library I'm working on, but it just dumps all of the classes together, all mixed up.  I'd like to separate them out by some sort of categorization under category headers.

Is that possible with dartdoc?  With categories? or some other mechanism?

If so, how does one do that?

Comment: I have been able to tag classes with '/// {@category Some Category}' and get those classes to show up in a 'Topics' list in the left sidebar.  Clicking a topic lists the classes in that topic (category).  It's a start.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the comment I posted seems pretty much the extent of what categories can do.

The real way to do this appears to be to bust up the source listing in sub-libraries so they list separately, then hide the main library with an `/// @nodoc` library comment.